# How split buf into two slice in one line code?

Tags: go

Split a `buf` into two slices.

One is

```
buf[:n]
```

other is

```
buf[n:].
```

`n` maybe larger than `len(buf)`.
Finish it just using one line code .

Is there any grace code ?

Comment: `a, b := buf[:n], buf[n:]`

Comment: if n larger than len(buf) . It will panic .panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range

Comment: If `n` is larger than `len(buf)`, then what you do you want to happen? Because then you can't `buf[n:]`.

Comment: I guess maybe there some system api can solve the problem? In one line code ?

Comment: Solve it how? To what? My question is the same, as above. Do you want `b` to be `nil` for example? Also why do you want to do this in one line? What difference does it make if it's one line or 2 lines?

Comment: This is an exercise  from  book . Maybe you give the right answer . I just consider too much .

Answer (score 0):

This is not elegant, nor practical, but the evaluation is on one line...

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    buf := "abcdefg"
    n := 8

    // fugly one-liner
    a, b, err := func() (string, string, error) {if n > len(buf) {return "", "", fmt.Errorf("out of bounds")} else {return buf[:n], buf[n:], nil}}()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Print(a + ":" + b)
    }
}
```